# ACCESS SQL (COUNT ISSUE)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Could anybody please help me on SQL command ON ACCESS
i Have 2 tables :

```
## customers ##            ## PREFERS_TO_BUY ##

ID | NAME                       ID  |  CAR 

52 |  GEORGE                    52  | TOYOTA
55 |  LUCAS                     55  | BMW
62 |  MARY                      55  |FERRARI
                                52  |MERCEDES
```

What i want is to create a query which will show me the name and id of customers and also the number of their car preferences , some like"

```
52|GEORGE|2
```

Thanks you very much!

Comment: did u tried anything? Homework?

Comment: its  part of a homework i have for introduction to acess. i Tried using a query where i would count the number of preferences and i could sho them with the id but i couldnt success also showing the name ( or the opposite)

Comment: You can edit your question to include what you have tried and the output you received.  If you show some effort, someone will help you.  We won't do your homework for you as you don't learn that way.  I will give you a hint, though, you need a subquery and/or join.

Comment: its a silly question...........

Answer (score 1):

This requires a simple join and application of a grouping:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Name, COUNT(p.ID) AS CarPreferences
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN PrefersToBuy p
ON c.ID = p.ID
GROUP BY c.ID, c.Name;
```

Comment: In future, please remember to show us your own attempts at solving your question.

Comment: Thanks you very much, well that was really fast, i was trying to write my try at the comments section but you sir were too fast, thanks you again